# DocumentDb partitioning strategy for real estate data

Tags: partitioning, azure-cosmosdb

Say I am building a documentdb collection of real estate properties in US and Canada (eventually, I may need to add other countries as well) and I expect to have several million documents in my collection. Also, let's assume that the most popular query will be to retrieve the top X properties within a certain radius from a given location.

Given these requirements, what would be a good partitioning strategy? Would using the ZIP code/Postal code be a good partitioning key? Would a strategy involving the geo location be better? Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I suggest that you use partitioned collections and use the id as your partition key then use geo queries. It's dirt simple and will get you maximum fan out on your queries which will give you the best throughput. Later, if that doesn't work, you can think about a more performant partitioning strategy.

Comment: I was under the impression that a partition strategy had to be 'logical' or 'predictable' in order to help Azure find the partition where the data is located. One example I see all the time is to use the first letter of a certain property to determine the partition. Am I wrong about this?

Comment: No, you are correct. When you have such a field, then use it. I use the TenantID for my partition key when I have that. That would be more efficient if you had such a field. However, in your case, the user will specify an address or a zip code. If the target properties are in the same zip code, then using the zip code as the partition key would be best. However, if you want to capture adjacent zip codes, then you'll need to search all partitions since you can't control into which partition the data gets put. In that case, random (my "use the id" suggestion) is as good as it gets.

Comment: Down the road, if that's not working out for you then maybe using the first 2 or 3 digits of a zip code would be more efficient. My fear there is that when you are near boundaries, you'd still need to search those. An even more sophisticated scheme where you keep a lookup table of the two-way minimum distance between two zip codes would be better but more complicated. You'd have to query that table first to find a list of zip codes within the specified distance and than use that to fan out your queries.

Comment: But my main point is to go with something as simple as possible for now. If/when you get big enough for that to be a bottleneck, then you can consider more complicated schemes.

Comment: Maybe I could use the state/province as my partition key? Sure, a search for properties within a certain radius could involve more than one state, but I bet most users would be ok with the limitation that I will only return data for one state at a time.

Comment: That would probably be more efficient if you can live with that limitation.